# How to replicate autogenerated primary key into another table

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET Core MVC, I am using code first migration. I have these two models:

Models:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Guardian { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool AdminPermition { get; set; }
}
```

Then the two are in a single ViewModel:

ViewModel:

```
public class StudentRegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(40)]
    public string Guardian { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Everything is saved using this service:

Service:

```
    public async Task<bool> RegistrationService(StudentRegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        try
        {
            //validation functions
            var context = new ValidationContext(registerModel, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            if (Validator.TryValidateObject(registerModel, context, results, true))
            {
                if (CheckEmailAvailability(registerModel.Email)){
                    if (registerModel.Password != registerModel.ConfirmPassword)
                        return false;
                    Student student = new Student
                    {
                        FirstName = registerModel.FirstName,
                        LastName = registerModel.LastName,
                        Email = registerModel.Email,
                        Guardian = registerModel.Guardian,
                        DateOfBirth = registerModel.DateOfBirth,
                        AdminPermition = false
                    };
                    User user = new User
                    {
                        Email = registerModel.Email,
                        Password = Encoder(registerModel.Password),
                    };

                    _context.Add(student);
                    _context.Add(user);

                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The **Id** in User is auto-generated, while the **Id** in Student is not.

How do I automatically duplicate the Id in User into the Id in Student?

Thanks

Comment: `automatically duplicate the Id in User into the Id in Student?` why do that? The question has nothing to do with MVC, a web framework. It has to do with EF Core, an ORM and database modeling. There's no replication involved either. What is the actual relation between `Student` and `User` and why should they share any information? Is there an inheritance relation? Or are `Student` and `User` entities independent? After all, a system's user isn't always a student. Even the same person could be a Student in one course and a Tutor in another. There may not be a User for every Student either

Comment: Mixing up the authentication model with the business model of an application is a bad idea too. In ASP.NET MVC Core there's already an authentication and authorization middleware with its own, secure account storage. Coupling these tables with business tables can only create conflicts - what happens when a student is enrolled first and only creates an account right before a course starts? What if that ID is an OAuth token only? What happens when a `User` is deleted?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - How about if I want to make the Id in User automatically a foreign key (userid) in Student. Thank

Comment: Why do that? You're still asking about your assumed solution, not the actual problem. Design issues aside, what you ask is to create a 1-1 relation. Like all relations, they're established by setting the appropriate navigation property. fbede's answer shows how to do that, although having a separate `UserId` field would be a lot better

Comment: On the other hand, the entire way the `User` is handled is wrong, plain and simple. Use the built-in Identity middleware, don't try to invent your own. Passwords shouldn't be encrypted or encoded, they need to be *salted and hashed* with an algorithm suitable for password hashing. These algorithms hash the salted password over 1000 times to ensure it's hard to use brute force to recover it.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Student")]
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    // ...
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```